# VBA Error when I activate another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am working on a sheet for my work but I'm stuck on something that I can't solve by searching on the internet.

I've got 2 sheets that I'm using at the moment.

Sheet 1: A database with all the information;
Sheet 2: A list with data taken out of Sheet1 and an option to add extra information by using a UserForm1.

- On Sheet2 I'm using a hyperlink to start up the UserForm1 with this code:

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
      If Target.Range.Column = "4" Then
          UserForm1.show
          Exit Sub
      End If
  End Sub
  ```

This worked good until I started working with code on the UserForm1. I made a Vlookup in the VBA UserForm1 with target on Sheet1. Now as soon as I click the hyperlink I get an error and the debug refers to the above code "UserForm1".

The UserForm1 Code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Object = ActiveCell
  TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Object, Sheet1.Range("$B$2:$BW$622"), 1, False)
  Label3 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
  Label5 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
End Sub

Private Sub BUT_Annuleren_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

The same happens when I use "Sheets("Sheet1").activate". Can someone help me with this to take information in my Userform1 out of multiple sheets?

Thanks for the help!

Ron

Comment: Please show your error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, don't forget to use the `Set` keyword when assigning objects.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set Object = ActiveCell
    TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Object, Sheet1.Range("$B$2:$BW$622"), 1, False)
    Label3 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Label5 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
End Sub

Private Sub BUT_Annuleren_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: I was looking in a whole other direction for the problem... but its solved now thanks!